# How to disambiguate links to methods in scaladoc?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, scaladoc, method-names, disambiguation

I'm documenting a Scala class with [overloaded methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading). How can I distinguish them when referring to them in scaladoc comments? For example, if I have

```
/**
 * The most important method is [[Doc.foo]].
 */
object Doc {
  def foo[A]: A = throw new UnsupportedOperationException;
  def foo[A,B >: A](x: A): B = x;
}
```

and run `sbt doc` I get

> Doc.scala:1: warning: The link target "Doc.foo" is ambiguous. Several (possibly overloaded) members fit the target:
>
> - method `foo[A,B>:A](x:A):B` in object Doc [chosen]
> - method `foo[A]:Nothing` in object Doc

Using `foo[A,B >: A]` etc. to the link doesn't work.

Comment: Would using `[[Doc.foo()]]` work? I know that in C# when there's an ambiguous reference in documentation, you have to either use `()` when you one the method without parameters or spell out the *argument types*, e.g. `foo(string)`. Maybe it's similar here...

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor That doesn't work, complains with: _warning: Could not find any member to link for "Doc.foo()"._

Comment: a PR at https://github.com/scala/docs.scala-lang adding documentation on this to http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scaladoc/for-library-authors.html would be welcome

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The following seems do the trick in Scala 2.10.

```
/**
 * The most important method is [[Doc.foo[A]:A*]].
 */
```

And here is some hint scaladoc gives me:

```
[warn] Quick crash course on using Scaladoc links
[warn] ==========================================
[warn] Disambiguating terms and types: Prefix terms with '$' and types with '!' in case both names are in use:
[warn]  - [[scala.collection.immutable.List!.apply class List's apply method]] and
[warn]  - [[scala.collection.immutable.List$.apply object List's apply method]]
[warn] Disambiguating overloaded members: If a term is overloaded, you can indicate the first part of its signature followed by *:
[warn]  - [[[scala.collection.immutable.List$.fill[A](Int)(⇒A):List[A]* Fill with a single parameter]]]
[warn]  - [[[scala.collection.immutable.List$.fill[A](Int,Int)(⇒A):List[List[A]]* Fill with a two parameters]]]
[warn] Notes: 
[warn]  - you can use any number of matching square brackets to avoid interference with the signature
[warn]  - you can use \. to escape dots in prefixes (don't forget to use * at the end to match the signature!)
[warn]  - you can use \# to escape hashes, otherwise they will be considered as delimiters, like dots.
```

Comment: I find it abominable that ScalDoc can't resolve names via imports. I refuse to use fully qualified names in documentation comments.

Comment: Apparently, the hint is displayed only if I use scaladoc directly. I used sbt, which didn't show it.

Comment: @Randall Schulz This should be fixed according to this issue: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3695

Comment: Alas, this has not consistently worked for me with complex type signatures.  But with simpler ones, it does.  (I have found no solution for more complex signatures.)

Comment: This answer was not helpful to me.  I'm trying to disambiguate 'apply' methods that have the same type args but different argument signatures.  And I need it to work with Intellij IDEA 'Quick Documentation' (Ctrl-Q) for viewing scaladoc of a method.

Comment: This information ought to be in the official doc. Volunteer to PR it? issue here: https://github.com/scala/docs.scala-lang/issues/1698

Comment: I believe this answer is out-of-date. please see https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scaladoc/for-library-authors.html#resolving-ambiguous-links-within-scaladoc-comments for current help

Answer (score 14):

What I found very usefull in `IntelliJ` is right clicking on a method you would like to put in [[ ]] and choosing "Copy reference".

Steps:

1. You find a method you'd like to reference somewhere else.

[image]

2. You right click on the method name and choose "Copy reference".

[image]

3. You paste it in [[ ]] in your documentation (and write a label of your choice next to it, e.g. "apply(String)").

[image]

4. Voilà.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me in IntelliJ 2019.3.4 Community. I had tried a lot of different things prior to reading your answer and was getting nowhere. Thank you so much.

Comment: Not always work for Scala, but in general it's a nice feature! Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 12):

I'm still surprised at how difficult it is to get this working and the lack of documentation for scaladoc itself. I decided to search the scala code base itself in hope of some useful examples. The best ones that I found were in https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/test/scaladoc/resources/links.scala. Hopefully this is useful for someone else who comes across this.

Answer (score 10):

I found a solution (apparently the unique solution) for complex signatures, by studying the doc of scaladoc.

- Don't use space in the signature
- Use the arguments name
- For argument types as well as return types, prefix all dots with a single backslash `\`
- Use the star `*` at the end of the signature
- Use the complete signature (as the ambiguous signatures are proposed to you). This step is optional, you may be able to stop the signature earlier, as long as you finish it with `*`

**Example:**

```
package org.my.stuff

class ReturnType

object Foo {
  class Bar {
    def lara(s: String): String = ???
    def lara(s: Foo.Bar): ReturnType= ???
  }
}

/** [[org.my.stuff.Foo$.Bar.lara(s:org\.my\.stuff\.Foo\.Bar):org\.my\.stuff\.ReturnType* The link to the right lara method]]
  */
object DocumentFooBarBingComplex {
}
```

Comment: "Don't use a space in the signature" -- What if there is an implicit parameter?

Comment: Alas, that would not work indeed. You may try adding \ in front of the space, or make sure you don't need to write up to the implicit parameters to disambiguate your code.